# Are there more settings for Nodejs cluster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop, pm2

Assumed you cluster your node app on a 4 CPU system, in 4 workers(childprocesses=new V8 instance) and each worker starts with about 10mb memory(default).

1. Is there a way to start them with more? like
   `--max-old-space-size=...`
2. And how can I pass in more V8-settings to workers?

( + how do strongloop and PM2 handle it? ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`cluster.setupMaster()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster_setupmaster_settings) to set the arguments passed to worker processes. Specifically there is an undocumented [`execArgv` setting that defaults to `process.execArgv`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/75c6d9dd95bbdb926d84cb3a9f518eff88651709/lib/cluster.js#L243), but you should be able to pass any array of node/v8-specific flags there.

Application arguments are passed via the `args` setting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `PM2` then it utilizes full `CPU` memory as on demand, since it provides a lot configuration for load balancing and performance.

If you want to utilize `CPU` with it, just increase the number of instances here

`pm2 start app.js -i 2`

where `i` is the number of instances you want to start.

While using `pm2` following steps are important:

`pm2 stop all`

`pm2 delete all`

`pm2 start app.js -i 2`

Always use `pm2 delete all` to unregister the CPU, since if you stop it, it still reserve the CPU.